# JMeter - websocket plugin - forbidden error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We are trying to test a WebSocket communication using the JMeter plugin(WebSocket request-response Sampler) by Peter Doornbosch. Headers are sent appropriately, response headers are received as intended with Response code:101. But the message says **{"message": "Forbidden", "connectionId":"xxxxxxxx=", "requestId":"xxxxxxxx="}**.

Answer (score 0):

"Headers are sent appropriately" - I doubt this is the case.

Compare requests which are being sent by JMeter and by the real browser (or other WebSocket client application) using an external sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) - the **requests must be exactly the same** (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)).

Given you will be sending the same request with JMeter as the real browser does you will be getting the same response

Also it might be the case of missing [authentication/authorization token](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security#authentication-authorization) which is normally being added to the URL